# When removing outliers in multiple columns, do I check the columns simultaneously or in succession?

Tags: outliers

Lets say I have following data:

| Row | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 101 |
| 2 | 12 | 102 |
| 3 | 13 | 103 |
| 4 | 14 | 104 |
| 5 | 15 | 105 |
| 6 | 40 | 106 |
| 7 | 16 | 107 |
| 8 | 17 | 108 |
| 9 | 18 | 112.7 |

Now lets say I would want to remove the outliers that are 1.5xIQR above the third quartile or 1.5xIQR below the first.
Looking at the data I have

|  | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. Quartile | 13 | 103 |
| Median | 15 | 105 |
| 3. Quartile | 17 | 107 |
| 1.5*IQR | 6 | 6 |

Now only row 6 has an outlier in the X column, because X=40 would be 1.5*IQR above of the 3. quartile of X. When I remove the whole row, then the new stats would look like:

|  | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. Quartile | 12.5 | 102.5 |
| Median | 14.5 | 104.5 |
| 3. Quartile | 16.5 | 106.5 |
| 1.5*IQR | 6 | 6 |

Now with the removal of one row we have a new outlier in row 9 in the Y column, because before the removal it was barely below the cut-off of 113 and now the 3. Quartile dropped to 112.5, which would make 112.7 an outlier.

Is this a wrong approach to outlier removal? How should I proceed from here on?

Comment: Please tell us *why* you are removing outliers.  I have to ask, because the algorithmic approach you are following is rarely useful.

Comment: I wanted to perform a regression on bivariate data. It looked like some values for both parameters had outliers and I was thinking that I should remove those before performing a regression. The reason I had this outliers is not because the measurements were incorrect but because it is a rare occurence. Imagine a survey of the Age of people that just married and then you have cases of 14 year olds or 95 year olds. I wanted to remove these edge cases.

Comment: Please add new info as an edit to the Q and not only in comments! Not everybody reads comments ...